# Prevent executing .htaccess of parent folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two different sites on same domain for example:
First site in the root directory **http://example.com/**
Second site in subfolder **http://example.com/site2/**
Each site have his own .htaccess
When i enter to second site (*http://example.com/site2/*), in log of mod_rewrite i see that apache trying to execute .htaccess of first site (*http://example.com/*).
So, the question is how to prevent this?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two sites hosted under the same root URL? The simplest solution is to fix that so that you actually have two sites, rather than a folder on one site that you consider a separate site.

Comment: Can you post your respective `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 2):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

**inherit**

> This forces the current configuration to inherit the configuration of
>   the parent. In per-virtual-server context, this means that the maps,
>   conditions and rules of the main server are inherited. In
>   per-directory context this means that conditions and rules of the
>   parent directory's .htaccess configuration are inherited.
>
> > `Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied after rules specified in the child scope.`

Answer (score 2):

While you can not stop the execution of the .htaccess in http://example.com

You CAN place another .htaccess in http://example.com/site2/ and any rule created here that overrides the rules in the .htaccess of the parent folder will be executed here but not in the parent folder.

For example, I recently had a case where I was rewriting any non-www version of my main site, which we'll call example.com to its www equivalent: www.example.com

The problem this caused is anyone going to my second site, which we'll call site2.com would actually redirect the user to www.example.com/site2.com/ even if the user enters site2.com OR www.site2.com OR http://www.site2.com in their browser's address input

What I had to do to fix it is makes changes in 2 .htaccess files, first in the root http://www.example.com then in a separate .htaccess located in http://www.example.com/site2.com/

1) http://www.example.com .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2) http://www.site2.com (http://www.example.com/site2.com/) .htaccess(this also forces the www version of site2.com):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com/site2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site2\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.site2\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Feel free to rip apart my regex, I am by no means a regex master. I also realize that this can creates 2 or maybe more extra redirects but this is the only way I could get this to work, without reassigning my DocumentRoot through through the host...which is probably a better option if your host can do it, mine would/could not...

Comment: "any rule created here that overrides the rules in the .htaccess of the parent folder will be executed here but not in the parent folder."  -- this is not really true. Both rules will execute, but the second one can reverse the effects of the first.