# stop htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I accessed a 'superfolder's .htaccess file and accidentally added

```
Rewrite / http://google.com/
```

This was done using php. Now I can't access php files in any directory to revert the change.

Is there anything I can do in a subdirectory of root to stop the redirect inside that folder?

Thank you.

And please don't ask more details about the 'accident'.. stupid mistake

Comment: Call admin of the server to remove that file/line ?

Comment: you can use command prompt for this.

Comment: you're not saying that you don't have FTP access to .htaccess? you should be able to delete it if nothing else I believe

Comment: You could overwrite the content of the file from elsewhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6665136/795876

Comment: I don't have ftp access thats why i used PHP to access the root directory.. I can't delete because the PHP script never runs (the redirect...)

Comment: Try `ssh yourhost` then `cd superdirectory` (whatever the directory is) then `rm .htaccess`. Edit: Scratch that, you don't have ssh access.

Comment: How do I use command line? I don't have ssh access to the remote server, only ftp and php..

Comment: Thanks for the laughs.. I deserve it :)

Comment: Does that not just redirect a request to `/`? Or is my Apache out of whack? What I mean is if you made `tmp.php` then you'd be requesting `/tmp.php` and it wouldn't get redirected? EDIT: Oh wait it's not mod_rewrite

Comment: That horrible line of code redirects anything after /. By the way, server admin doesn't know anything yet.

Comment: From next time onwards, make rewrite to your directory files. Call admin of the server say what you done and make a apologize. I don't think it have any other soln.. :)

Comment: @matejkramny So you have FTP access but not FTP access to the higher directoy, but your PHP access CAN write to the higher directory, right?

Comment: @matejkramny is the directive `RewriteRule` or `Redirect`? Because `Rewrite` isn't a valid apache mod_rewrite directive.

Comment: @JonLin Redirect. Not using mod_rewrite at all..

Comment: I contacted server admin, both laughed at it.. Still interesting though how to stop it redirecting although it shouldn't happen if I use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I contacted server admin, both laughed at it.. Still interesting though how to stop it redirecting although it shouldn't happen if I use mod_rewrite.

With mod_alias' `Redirect`, you're screwed. That directive is applied across the board, starting from the path-node where the htaccess file sits (if it's in an htaccess file), or the path-node of the `<Directory>` block that it sits in. So the only solution is to get an admin to remove it.

With mod_rewrite however, with an htaccess file, it doesn't act the same as within a `<Directory>` block. Rules inside an htaccess file in a path-node inside a directory has precedence over rules inside an htaccess file in the parent directory. So if you had 2 htaccess files:

*/.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/? http://google.com/
```

and in */tmp/.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?tmp/ http://stackoverflow.com/
```

And you go to `http://yourdomain.com/tmp/`, you'll get redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com/` because the rules in the tmp directory has precedence over the rules in the parent directory. In face, the rules in the parent directory aren't applied at all unless you've used the [`RewriteOptions Inherit` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) to inherit any rules from the parent directory.

Because of this, you can simply create an htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Use FTP to upload it to your subdirectory, and upload the php file that you used to change the parent directory's htaccess file. Then just use your browser and go to that php file in the subdirectory.

Having simply turned on the rewrite engine in your subdirectory, without any rules, means:

1. I have mod_rewrite active in this directory
2. Since the rewrite engine is turned on in this directory, ignore all rules in the all parent directories.
3. Since the mod_rewrite ruleset is blank (no actual `RerwiteRule`'s) nothing happens at all
4. Accessing this directory, eventhough the rewrite engine is on, mod_rewrite does nothing so it's as if the rewrite engine is turned off.

Sounds counter-intuitive, but that's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Connect using your FTP client. Enable hidden files in your FTP client (try FileZilla, this one lets you do that). Delete `.htaccess` in your superdirectory. If this file has other data in it, copy it to your local computer, make changes and upload it again.

Here is some more help: http://www.intrepid.com.au/how-to-view-htaccess-with-filezilla/

Comment: Ouch... If you can't find another way, let the system administrator know. You shouldn't have been able to modify that `.htaccess` file in the first place.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about FTP permissions.. It runs under different user and sometimes you are able to modify system files with it if not set up correctly